# React filtering with checkboxes

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox, conditional-statements, filtering

I struggle so bad about making a filtered array with checkbox inputs. My issue is I can do just filtering by just one of the filtering conditions.

For example, if I checked 3 of the checkboxes e.g breakfast, pool, and gym, I only want those true ones of all my array objects that wanted to be filtered. But instead of that, it's still filtering the truest ones of the array. Including not the true ones. When I checked all the features, If all my conditions aren't true, I want it to say "no match".

I know my code is a little bit messy but if you can help me I would be so grateful.

Thank you.

Context API:

```
const [myHotel] = useState(
            [
            {
                id: uuidv4(),
                title: "Beach Hotel",
                avaibleRoom: 16,
                hotel_img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566073771259-6a8506099945?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                hotel_room_img: [
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570214476695-19bd467e6f7a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559599189-fe84dea4eb79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582582484783-0a7a9e45b0d6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                       ],    
                luks: false,
                maxCapacity: 39,
                breakfast: true,
                freeotopark: true,
                pool: true,
                wifi: true,
                gym: false,
                bar: true,
                beach: true,
                minigolf: false,
                price: 1730,
            },
    
            {
                id: uuidv4(),
                title: "Luxurios Hotel",
                avaibleRoom: 17,
                hotel_img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520250497591-112f2f40a3f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                hotel_room_img: [
                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559599238-308793637427?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565330502637-963b256876c6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1349&q=80",
                    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559599242-651c4e085efb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                ],  
                luks: true,
                maxCapacity: 51,
                breakfast: true,
                freeotopark: false,
                pool: true,
                wifi: true,
                gym: true,
                bar: false,
                beach: true,
                minigolf: false,
                price: 2670,
            },
```

Here is my functions:

```
function Hotels() {
     /** CONTEXT API DATA **/
     const hotelContext = useContext(HotelsContext); 
    const {myHotel} = hotelContext; 
    
    /** NEW FILTERED HOTEL STATE  **/
    const [newHotel, setNewHotel] = useState([]);

   /** checkboxes true or false data**/
    const [handleCheck, setHandleCheck] = useState({});
    

     const handleChange =  (e) => {
            setHandleCheck({...handleCheck, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked})
        }

       useEffect(() => {
        function filterbyName (value) {
            if(handleCheck !== undefined) {
                if(handleCheck.breakfast === true) {
                    return value.breakfast === true
                } else if (handleCheck.luks === true) {
                    return value.luks === true
                } else if (handleCheck.freeotopark === true) {
                    return value.freeotopark === true
                } else if (handleCheck.pool === true) {
                    return value.pool === true
                } else if (handleCheck.wifi === true) {
                    return value.wifi === true
                } else if (handleCheck.gym === true) {
                    return value.gym === true
                } else if (handleCheck.bar === true) {
                    return value.bar === true
                } else if (handleCheck.beach === true) {
                    return value.beach === true
                } else if (handleCheck.minigolf === true) {
                    return value.minigolf === true
                } else {
                    return value
                }
            } else {
                return value
            }
        }
      
        setNewHotel(
            myHotel.filter(filterbyName)
        )
       }, [handleCheck, myHotel])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `filterbyName` function is wrong. Once it reaches a defined filter option, it immediately returns an answer based on whether the current value passes that filter or not, without checking any other filters. From your question i understand that you would like to apply all the filters to your values, in which case the function should look something like this:

```
function filterbyName (value) {
    if (handleCheck !== undefined) {
        let valuePassesFilters = true; // NOTE 1

        if (handleCheck.breakfast === true) {
            valuePassesFilters = valuePassesFilters && value.breakfast === true; // NOTE 2
        }
        
        if (handleCheck.luks === true) {
            valuePassesFilters &&= value.luks === true; // NOTE 3
        }
        
        // ...same thing for all other filters
        
        return valuePassesFilters;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

`NOTE 1`: Instantiate a temporary variable holding the answer to the question whether a value will pass all the filters or not. Currently it does, since you haven't subjected it to any checks yet, so initially it's `true`.

`NOTE 2`: If a filter is checked, subject the `value` to the test. If the result is `true`, then `valuePassesFilters` will remain `true`. Once it becomes `false` then passing any other filters won't help, it will remain `false` as it should.

`NOTE 3`: this is just a shorthand notation for the operation at `NOTE 2`.

Also, please note the lack of `else` between the `if` statements, as you need to go through all of them.

Later edit: here is an equivalent solution which i think is more elegant and saves you from writing so many if statements as fields get added to your model (along with filters for them):

```
function filterbyName (value) {
    if (handleCheck !== undefined) {
        let filterKeys = ['breakfast', 'luks', 'freeotopark', 'pool', 'wifi', 'gym', 'bar', 'beach', 'minigolf'];

        return filterKeys.every(function(key) {
            return !handleCheck[key] || value[key];
        });
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Here we simply declare the filters we want to check our values against in an array: `filterKeys`. The `every` function iterates through the filters as long as the callback returns true, and stops at the first `false` it encounters. The condition in the callback is pretty nice: we want to return `true` and keep going if either the current filter is **not applied** (`!handleCheck[key]`, which will skip evaluation of the 2nd condition), or if not (which means the filter **is applied**) then keep going if the `value` passes the test (`value[key]`). In the end `value` either passes all filters and we return `true` after checking all of them, or if not then we immediately return `false` on the first filter it doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and solution. It worked so well. I've struggled to figure this out for hours

Comment: @KadirÜretir glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want only the hotels that match *all* of the checked boxes instead of *any* of the checked boxes. If that's the case, I'd suggest enumerating the selected amenity names and testing whether the hotel in question has true for all of those properties.

Most of the example snippet below is just getting set up, creating the checkboxes, etc.

The bit you're probably going to be most interested in is the `filterHotels` function, and the last line of it in particular:

```js
    function filterHotels () {
      // convenience function for extracting the name from an object
      const getName = ({name}) => name;
      
      // get the list of checked boxes and extract their names
      const checked = [...inputsList.querySelectorAll(':checked')].map(getName);
      
      // return the hotels that include every checked amenity
      return hotels.filter(h => checked.every(amenity => h[amenity])).map(getName);
    }
```

Assuming you know the names of the selected amenities, finding the hotels that include all of them is straightforward: Filter the hotels to include only those where [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) checked amenity name is present/true.

```js
// just a convenience for creating the checkboxes
const amenities = ['pool','gym','wifi','breakfast','bar','beach'];

// sample data with varying amenities
const hotels = [
  {
    name: 'Hotel with pool, gym, wifi',
    pool: true,
    gym: true,
    wifi: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hotel with gym and pool',
    pool: true,
    gym: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hotel with breakfast and wifi',
    breakfast: true,
    wifi: true,    
  },  
];

// utility function for adding a checkbox with the given name
const addCheckbox = name => {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.innerHTML = `<label><input type="checkbox" name="${name}" /> ${name}</label>`;
  inputsList.appendChild(item);
}

// get a reference to the dom element containing the checkboxes
const inputsList = document.getElementById('inputs');

// creates the checkboxes, attaches the onchange handler
function setup () {  
  // create a checkbox for each amenity
  amenities.forEach(a => addCheckbox(a));

  // checkbox onChange handler;
  // get the filtered hotel list and emit it to the console
  const output = () => console.log(filterHotels());
  
  // attach the onchange listener to each checkbox
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
    .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', output));
    
  // emit the initial list, before any clicks
  output();
}

// filter the list of hotels according to checked amenities
function filterHotels () {
  // convenience function for extracting the name from an object
  const getName = ({name}) => name;
  
  // get the list of checked boxes and extract their names
  const checked = [...inputsList.querySelectorAll(':checked')].map(getName);
  
  // return the hotels that include every checked amenity
  return hotels.filter(h => checked.every(amenity => h[amenity])).map(getName);
}

// kick it off
setup();
```

```html
<ul id="inputs"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The other solution above is worked for me but I hope someone would benefits from your solution.